# Не получается создать кнопку, хотя hWnd не равен нулю

Tags: python, winapi, ctypes

Я использую такой Python код:

```py
import os, __main__, sys;

file = __main__.__file__;

import ctypes;
from ctypes import wintypes;

user32   = ctypes.windll.user32;
gdi32    = ctypes.windll.gdi32;
kernel32 = ctypes.windll.kernel32;

WNDPROC = ctypes.WINFUNCTYPE(
    ctypes.c_long,
    ctypes.c_int,
    ctypes.c_uint,
    ctypes.c_int,
    ctypes.c_int,
)

class WNDCLASS(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [('style',         ctypes.c_uint),
                ('lpfnWndProc',   WNDPROC),
                ('cbClsExtra',    ctypes.c_int),
                ('cbWndExtra',    ctypes.c_int),
                ('hInstance',     ctypes.c_int),
                ('hIcon',         ctypes.c_int),
                ('hCursor',       ctypes.c_int),
                ('hbrBackground', ctypes.c_int),
                ('lpszMenuName',  ctypes.c_wchar_p),
                ('lpszClassName', ctypes.c_wchar_p)]

colors = {
    "aliceblue": "#f0f8ff",
    "antiquewhite": "#faebd7",
    "aqua": "#00ffff",
    "aquamarine": "#7fffd4",
    "azure": "#f0ffff",
    "beige": "#f5f5dc",
    "bisque": "#ffe4c4",
    "black": "#000000",
    "blanchedalmond": "#ffebcd",
    "blue": "#0000ff",
    "blueviolet": "#8a2be2",
    "brown": "#a52a2a",
    "burlywood": "#deb887",
    "cadetblue": "#5f9ea0",
    "chartreuse": "#7fff00",
    "chocolate": "#d2691e",
    "coral": "#ff7f50",
    "cornflowerblue": "#6495ed",
    "cornsilk": "#fff8dc",
    "crimson": "#dc143c",
    "cyan": "#00ffff",
    "darkblue": "#00008b",
    "darkcyan": "#008b8b",
    "darkgoldenrod": "#b8860b",
    "darkgray": "#a9a9a9",
    "darkgrey": "#a9a9a9",
    "darkgreen": "#006400",
    "darkkhaki": "#bdb76b",
    "darkmagenta": "#8b008b",
    "darkolivegreen": "#556b2f",
    "darkorange": "#ff8c00",
    "darkorchid": "#9932cc",
    "darkred": "#8b0000",
    "darksalmon": "#e9967a",
    "darkseagreen": "#8fbc8f",
    "darkslateblue": "#483d8b",
    "darkslategray": "#2f4f4f",
    "darkslategrey": "#2f4f4f",
    "darkturquoise": "#00ced1",
    "darkviolet": "#9400d3",
    "deeppink": "#ff1493",
    "deepskyblue": "#00bfff",
    "dimgray": "#696969",
    "dimgrey": "#696969",
    "dodgerblue": "#1e90ff",
    "firebrick": "#b22222",
    "floralwhite": "#fffaf0",
    "forestgreen": "#228b22",
    "fuchsia": "#ff00ff",
    "gainsboro": "#dcdcdc",
    "ghostwhite": "#f8f8ff",
    "gold": "#ffd700",
    "goldenrod": "#daa520",
    "gray": "#808080",
    "grey": "#808080",
    "green": "#008000",
    "greenyellow": "#adff2f",
    "honeydew": "#f0fff0",
    "hotpink": "#ff69b4",
    "indianred": "#cd5c5c",
    "indigo": "#4b0082",
    "ivory": "#fffff0",
    "khaki": "#f0e68c",
    "lavender": "#e6e6fa",
    "lavenderblush": "#fff0f5",
    "lawngreen": "#7cfc00",
    "lemonchiffon": "#fffacd",
    "lightblue": "#add8e6",
    "lightcoral": "#f08080",
    "lightcyan": "#e0ffff",
    "lightgoldenrodyellow": "#fafad2",
    "lightgray": "#d3d3d3",
    "lightgrey": "#d3d3d3",
    "lightgreen": "#90ee90",
    "lightpink": "#ffb6c1",
    "lightsalmon": "#ffa07a",
    "lightseagreen": "#20b2aa",
    "lightskyblue": "#87cefa",
    "lightslategray": "#778899",
    "lightslategrey": "#778899",
    "lightsteelblue": "#b0c4de",
    "lightyellow": "#ffffe0",
    "lime": "#00ff00",
    "limegreen": "#32cd32",
    "linen": "#faf0e6",
    "magenta": "#ff00ff",
    "maroon": "#800000",
    "mediumaquamarine": "#66cdaa",
    "mediumblue": "#0000cd",
    "mediumorchid": "#ba55d3",
    "mediumpurple": "#9370db",
    "mediumseagreen": "#3cb371",
    "mediumslateblue": "#7b68ee",
    "mediumspringgreen": "#00fa9a",
    "mediumturquoise": "#48d1cc",
    "mediumvioletred": "#c71585",
    "midnightblue": "#191970",
    "mintcream": "#f5fffa",
    "mistyrose": "#ffe4e1",
    "moccasin": "#ffe4b5",
    "navajowhite": "#ffdead",
    "navy": "#000080",
    "oldlace": "#fdf5e6",
    "olive": "#808000",
    "olivedrab": "#6b8e23",
    "orange": "#ffa500",
    "orangered": "#ff4500",
    "orchid": "#da70d6",
    "palegoldenrod": "#eee8aa",
    "palegreen": "#98fb98",
    "paleturquoise": "#afeeee",
    "palevioletred": "#db7093",
    "papayawhip": "#ffefd5",
    "peachpuff": "#ffdab9",
    "peru": "#cd853f",
    "pink": "#ffc0cb",
    "plum": "#dda0dd",
    "powderblue": "#b0e0e6",
    "purple": "#800080",
    "red": "#ff0000",
    "rosybrown": "#bc8f8f",
    "royalblue": "#4169e1",
    "saddlebrown": "#8b4513",
    "salmon": "#fa8072",
    "sandybrown": "#f4a460",
    "seagreen": "#2e8b57",
    "seashell": "#fff5ee",
    "sienna": "#a0522d",
    "silver": "#c0c0c0",
    "skyblue": "#87ceeb",
    "slateblue": "#6a5acd",
    "slategray": "#708090",
    "slategrey": "#708090",
    "snow": "#fffafa",
    "springgreen": "#00ff7f",
    "steelblue": "#4682b4",
    "tan": "#d2b48c",
    "teal": "#008080",
    "thistle": "#d8bfd8",
    "tomato": "#ff6347",
    "turquoise": "#40e0d0",
    "violet": "#ee82ee",
    "wheat": "#f5deb3",
    "white": "#ffffff",
    "whitesmoke": "#f5f5f5",
    "yellow": "#ffff00",
    "yellowgreen": "#9acd32",
}

class Color():
    def __init__(self, red_name_or_hex, green=None, blue=None):
        if type(red_name_or_hex) == str:
            if red_name_or_hex[0] == '#':
                _hex = red_name_or_hex.lstrip('#');
            else:
                name = red_name_or_hex;
                _hex = colors[name].lstrip('#');
            red, green, blue = [int(_hex[i:i+2], 16) for i in (0, 2, 4)];
        else:
            red = red_name_or_hex;
        self.__rgb__ = (red, green, blue);
    def get(self):
        return self.__rgb__;

class Window():
    def __procedure__(self, hWnd, message, wParam, lParam):
        if message == 2:
            user32.PostQuitMessage(0);
            return 0;
        elif message == 15:
            return 0;
        return user32.DefWindowProcW(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    
    __wndclass__ = WNDCLASS()
    __wndclass__.style          = 1 | 2
    __wndclass__.cbClsExtra     = 0
    __wndclass__.cbWndExtra     = 0
    __wndclass__.hInstance      = kernel32.GetModuleHandleW(ctypes.c_int(0))
    __wndclass__.hIcon          = user32.LoadIconW(ctypes.c_int(0), ctypes.c_int(32512))
    __wndclass__.hCursor        = user32.LoadCursorW(ctypes.c_int(0), ctypes.c_int(32512))
    __wndclass__.lpszMenuName   = None
    
    def __init__(self, title, width, height, x=-2147483648, y=-2147483648, background=Color('white')):
        frames = list(sys._current_frames().values());
        variables = {};
        for frame in frames:
            variables.update(frame.f_locals);
            while(frame := frame.f_back):
                variables.update(frame.f_locals);
         
        count = 0;
        for name, value in variables.items():
            if isinstance(value, Window):
                count += 1;
        
        self.__wndclassname__ = "PyWin_" + os.path.splitext(file)[0] + "#" + str(count);
        
        self.__wndclass__.hbrBackground  = gdi32.CreateSolidBrush(wintypes.RGB(*background.get()))
        self.__wndclass__.lpfnWndProc    = WNDPROC(self.__procedure__);
        self.__wndclass__.lpszClassName  = self.__wndclassname__;
        
        if not user32.RegisterClassW(ctypes.byref(self.__wndclass__)):
            raise SystemError();
        
        self.__hWnd__ = user32.CreateWindowExW(
            0,
            self.__wndclass__.lpszClassName,
            title,
            13565952,
            x,
            y,
            width,
            height,
            0,
            0,
            self.__wndclass__.hInstance,
            0,
        );
    def start(self):
        msg = wintypes.MSG()
        pMsg = ctypes.pointer(msg)
        while user32.GetMessageW(pMsg, ctypes.c_int(0), 0, 0) != 0:
            user32.TranslateMessage(pMsg);
            user32.DispatchMessageW(pMsg);
    def show(self):
        user32.ShowWindow(self.__hWnd__, 8);
        user32.UpdateWindow(self.__hWnd__);
class Button():
    def __init__(self, parent, text, x, y, width=-2147483648, height=-2147483648):
        self.__hWnd__ = user32.CreateWindowExW(
            0,
            "button",
            text,
            1073741824 | 268435456 | 8388608,
            x,
            y,
            width,
            height,
            parent.__hWnd__,
            0,
            kernel32.GetModuleHandleW(ctypes.c_int(0)),
            0,
        );
        user32.ShowWindow(self.__hWnd__, 5);
        user32.UpdateWindow(self.__hWnd__);
wnd = Window('Python 3D graphics', 1000, 500, background=Color('green'));
btn = Button(wnd, 'hello', 10, 10);
wnd.show();
wnd.start();
```

Но почему-то не создаётся кнопка.

Comment: А нельзя было все импорты написать, вы это специально, чтобы никто не мог сразу запустить код?

Comment: Теперь хотя бы воспроизводится. Но пока SystemError, потом ещё гляну